# Failed Unity Gradle Build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I've installed Unity with GVRDemo from Google Developers:

[GVRDemo](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/get-started)

When I select build and run it throws up the following exception:

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I've checked the SDK Manager to make sure I have the matching platform for my Android phone. And I've checked for anything obvious in the Android Manifest created by Unity. I'm at a loss. What would be the first point of call with this exception?

Comment: show you android studio version

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1. Downloaded it yesterday right after installing Unity.

Comment: because android studio 3.0 remove the aapt, so ,you must changed you library to others .

Comment: which library? In Unity?